# Часть фраз в WooCommerce не переводится через Loco Translate. Почему?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, перевод

Дано: WP + WooCommerce + Loco Translate. Переводим с английского на русский.

После ряда апргрейтов движка и плагинов "сломались" некоторые переводы. В частности, надпись на кнопке "Add to cart" в листинге товаров переводится, а в карточке товара - нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашел файл-источник надписи. Если я в нем меняю надпись, изменения на сайте тотчас появляются.
Файл /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstract/abstract-wc-product.php

[image: Файл /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstract/abstract-wc-product.php]

Запись о нем присутствует в соответствующем .po файле
Файл \languages\loco\plugins\woocommerce-ru_RU.po

[image: Файл \languages\loco\plugins\woocommerce-ru_RU.po]

В самом Loco Translate, фраза переведена, других вхождений нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Других файлов перевода нет.

Итого - фраза включена в файл перевода, файл рабочий, перевод на сайте не появляется.

Почему фраза не переводится? Куда рыть, что проверить, может какие-то идеи?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> Почему фраза не переводится? Куда рыть, что проверить, может какие-то
> идеи? Заранее спасибо!

Потому что это уже выводит тема или другой плагин.

Для перевода строк можно использовать [Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) или [Say what?](https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/).
*Я предпочитаю первый, тк обычно переводить приходится не мало.*

Comment: >> Потому что это уже выводит тема или другой плагин.

А как мне это поймать? Я делал поиск по всем файлам сайта по фразе "Add to cart", других способов не могу придумать.

Comment: @Viktor наиболее просто - методом переключения на дефолтную тему и отключением подозрительных" плагинов. (а по всем файлам сайта искать ненужно. Искать можно только по плагинам и используемой теме).

Comment: Обновил ответ. Можешь искать и с помощью Loco

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была, как и подсказал @SeVlad, в другом плагине - Contact Form 7 Captcha, а возможно в плагине Contact Form 7. Возможно плагины как-то криво обновились или все-таки конфилктовали. Я по итогу еще раз обновил CF7, а CF7reCaptcha снес, так как функционал капчи есть в CF7. И тогда все переводы исправились.